# Do you check if inflated view is null or not?

Tags: android

Here is a simple method:

```
 private void setupUI(Context context) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_section_view, this);
        header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_section_header);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_section_listview);
    }
```

Lint is advising to check `view` is it `null` or not. Do you guys usually check such conditions? If it is really `null` because somebody deleted layout xml, you can check it and throw `NullPointerException` but it would be thrown anyway... so what's the point?

Comment: If you test view for null state you're able to prevent the exception? I'd say that is a pretty good point :)

Comment: You don't need to prevent a Runtime exception because something wrong happened not because of your logic fail, but because you lack a resource, so you better crash and restore the file which has been deleted. I just don't understand Lint's advice for checking if view is null.

Comment: Sure, if you're not aiming for a stable app then I see no problem in that. But it is much more appreciated to tell the user what happened and how to fix it. I guess that is why Lint suggest you check for null state.

Comment: I don't know the greater context but I don't think inflate actually add the view to the view hierarchy? So is view being dropped after this method call except for the fact you have instance variables pointing to it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you check if inflated view is null or not?

No, I don't. If it is `null` I can't handle it during run-time, so I prefer to get instant error and fix it (probably it's wrong filename or something easy).

> Do you guys usually check such conditions?

Depends on a condition... Usually yes, usually Lint has good ideas.

> so what's the point?

To read more about this warning, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> on your Lint warning and select <kbd>Explain issue...</kbd>

If you want to get rid of this warning, you can use [`@SuppressLint`](http://tools.android.com/recent/ignoringlintwarnings) annotation.

In earlier versions of Lint this warning didn't exist.